# Invoking a method from dll [c#]

Tags: c#, dll, methods, call, invoke

please tell me how to invoke method from the dll, you can even with the usual primitive MessageBox.Show ("Hello MessageBox"); .
If anything, I loaded the library so ...

```
    private void LoadPlugins(string path)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");

        foreach (string fname in files)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(fname);

            foreach (Type t in asm.GetExportedTypes())
            {
                if (typeof(PluginIface.IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                {
                    PluginIface.IPlugin pi = (PluginIface.IPlugin)asm.CreateInstance(t.FullName);

                    pi.shwdialog(); // Here the window should appear)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The file with the interface.

```
namespace PluginIface
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void shwdialog();
    }
}
```

File plugin

```
namespace plg
{
    public class Plugin1 : IPlugin
    {
        public Plugin1()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Plugin1 start");
        }

        public void shwdialog()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello MessageBox");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add reference with the .dll

Comment: Are you planning to use a Plugin architecture or simply want to know, how to call a method from a dll.

Comment: Was doing not help :( .The error appears in the "foreach (Type t in asm.GetExportedTypes ())", with the addition of: Exception type "System.TypeLoadException" appeared in mscorlib.dll, but it was not handled in user code
Additional information: No implementation of the method "shwdialog" in style "loaddll.Plugin1" from the assembly "loaddll, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null".

Comment: Thank you help, only works with Console.WriteLine ("Plugin1 start"); and if I add MessageBox.Show ("Hello MessageBox"); it does not compile the plugin, with an "Error CS0103    name" MessageBox "does not exist in the current context."

Comment: If the DLL is a managed assembly, just reference it in the project. If it's unmanaged, usw `DLLImport`.